# Transform pandas dataframe into numpy array for fast plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, spyder

I am writting a script to plot some data.
I am using python 3.7.1 on windows and have the following code to plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files=['path']


for i in range(len(files)):
    data = pd.read_csv(files[i], sep=';', skiprows=17, header=None,engine='python', decimal=",")

    c=files[0].split('\\')
    path='\\'.join(c[:-1])

    x= data.loc[:,0].values
    y= data.loc[:,1].values
    c,data=None,None

    plt.ioff() #turns off the plotting 
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel('x]')
    plt.ylabel('y')

    plt.savefig(path+'\\ title123') #saves image
```

I want to transform the dataframe from pandas into a numpy array dtype float64.
Currently, the code I have transforms the data into an object type. I cannot plot this because the code is taking too long to run.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,10,1000000)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I will leave a link to the file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kir-cGlk3bZSLmvD_tfnbGUaTYzvcW-3
Can anyone give me a help?

Kind Regards!

Comment: Are you that the problem is not, that reading the csv takes long?

Comment: What he meant is... what's the CSV size, how many columns and rows? Also, when importing the csv, do you really need the `engine='python'` ? `python` is slower than `c`, as stated here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: yes, the bottleneck is probably when you read the file, especially that you use the python engine and not the C one. maybe you can do a %prun on 1 loop to see what takes time. Also, if you have object, and not float by default, there might be a reason for this (like you have non-float value, could be nan).

Comment: `data = data.astype(np.float64)` would convert your dataframe to numbers... ***if*** it is convertible. Also you may need to convert your index independently. The question does not provide any details about the data at all, so one cannot really say anything specific here.

Comment: The file as 30000 lines. Importing the file it does quite fast. In what regards plotting it takes a lot of time and I have to reset the kernel.
When I use the "c" engine I get an error :OSError: Initializing from file failed

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that it was a problem with ',' and '.'. Sort of a math "language" conflict.

However, the for loop runs extremely slow when more than one file is loaded.

Kind regards to all!